# How is momentum conserved in magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, momentum, conservation-laws

In a uniform perpendicular magnetic field , force on charged particle cause change in direction of momentum. How do we explain it using conservation of momentum?

I don't know what is Hamilton or canonical or something like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is momentum conserved when a magnet attracts a metal?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75171/) or [Is the canonical momentum conserved when a particle moves in magnetic field?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98583/)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform First question couldn't answer my question and second question I couldn't understand.

Comment: The second linked answer is saying the following: kinetic momentum (like the Newtonian $p=mv$) is *not* conserved in a magnetic field. However, there is a generalization of momentum that is conserved. This generalization (which does not have a simple name that I know of, unfortunately) is found by the appropriate generalization of the law of conservation of momentum, which comes from translational invariance of the system and Noether's theorem.

Comment: You explain it by measuring the movement of the apparatus that causes the magnetic field. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne Thankyou !!! It really and clearly solved it.  Just one thing more, if charge moves in circular motion will apparatus also move in circle?

Comment: What do you think? :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne I think it will tend to move in circle but we will prevent it by holding it.  I got it!! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Electromagnetic field itself can be ascribed momentum in such a way that momentum is locally conserved (i.e. momentum of a space region changes continuously and its rate of change can be expressed as a surface integral of certain field function).